# Enforce setting values when installing Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

How can I define a value in `values.yaml` in a way that will force a user to override this value when installing the chart?

The idea is to use `values.yaml` as an interface declaration + default values storage. The issue is that not all values can have default values. Those values therefore must be specified by the chart's user.

Comment: Is [`required` function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#know-your-template-functions) (e.g. `value: {{ required "A valid .Values.who entry required!" .Values.who }}`) what you are looking for?